# Riemann Integrability of a simple function

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$ f(x) =\begin{cases}\frac{x^2}{2}+4 & x \geq 0\\-\frac{x^2}{2}+2 & x < 0\end{cases} $$

Is $f(x)$ Riemann integrable in the interval $[-1, 2] ?$

Does there exist a function $g(x)$ such that $g'(x)=f(x)$ ?

Solution: I can see that the function is Riemann Integrable as there is only one point of discontinuity in the interval mentioned.

Also by First fundamental theorem of calculus there exists a function $g(t)$ such that

$\displaystyle g(t)=\int_{-1}^t f(x) \, dx$ where $t$ is in the interval $[-1, 2]$

But $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$. Thatwould mean $g'(c) \neq f(c)$ at all points in the interval.

What does it mean? Does there exist $g(x)$ as asked in the problem?

Comment: Recall [Darboux's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_%28analysis%29).

Comment: I went through it. So does this mean that every Riemann Integrable function has a corresponding $g(x)$ which satisfies $g'(x)=f(x)$ at all points in the interval, irrespective of the number of discontinuities of the function $f(x)$?

Comment: No. It means that if $f$ is a derivative, then $f$ has the intermediate value property. Your function $f$ does not have the intermediate value property; so, it is not a derivative. (You can also use a different argument, not appealing to Darbouc: you can define $g$ explicitly for $x\ne0$ piecewise. Then show $g'(0)$ does not exist by looking at the left-hand and right-hand derivatives of $g$ at $x=0$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose such a function $g$ exists.  Try finding the one-sided derivatives of $g$ at $0$:

$$
\lim_{h\,\downarrow\,0} \frac{g(0+h)-g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\,\downarrow\,0} \frac{\int_0^h f(x)\,dx}{h}= \lim_{h\,\downarrow\,0} \frac 1 h \left[ \frac{x^3}{6}+4x \right]_{x:=0}^{x:=h} = \lim_{h\,\downarrow\,0} \left(\frac{h^2}{6} + 4\right) = 4.
$$

Then find the other one-sided derivative, involving $\displaystyle\lim_{h\,\uparrow\,0}$.  If they're not equal, then there can be no function $g$ satisfying the requirements.

Answer (score -1):

By the first fundamental theorem of calculus, the function $$g(t)=\int_a^t f(x) dx$$ has a derivative in all points where $f$ is continuous. In those points, $g'(t) = f(t)$.

Comment: So Does there exist a function such that $g'(x)=f(x)$?

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you haven't said the function $g$ defined in that way has a derivative ONLY at points where $f$ is continuous.